# asp.mvc 4 more routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

I have an web app build with asp.net MVC 4.
I want to have the following 3 types of routes:

> 1. /action
> 2. /action/id
> 3. /id/id2

In global.asax I have changed the routes as it follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Without Action",
           url: "{id}/{id2}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "City_Category" },
           namespaces: new[] { "Namespace.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Without Controller",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Namespace.Controllers" }
        );
```

But when I try an {action}/{id} it goes to the first route defined in global.asax. Works only if url is {action} or {id}/{id2}.

How can I make to work all 3 routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `{id}` and `{id2}` will always be numeric, you can add a constraint to the route so that it will only kick in when those values are digits:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Without Action",
           url: "{id}/{id2}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "City_Category" },
           new { id = @"\d+", id2 = @"\d+" }
           namespaces: new[] { "Namespace.Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: {id} and {id2} will be string

Comment: Well in that case there is no way the router can distinguish if the string you pass is an id or an action. What you can do, using the same method in this answer, is restrict the {action}/{id} route to a subset of string, for example: `new { action = @"[Index|Edit|Create]" }`. Remember to put it above the other one because they get evaluated in order...

Comment: I have tried to put this route first but in this way the second route with the 2 ids didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use http://attributerouting.net/, you can define routes by attributes, which is a very easy to define routes, especially if you end up with a lot of complex routes. I had about 30 route definitions and a lot of comments how the url looks like for each action. I could remove all comments and route definitions with these attributes.